# Codeception - how to run acceptance tests in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, codeception

Anyone could you help me to run Acceptance tests in chrome

1) My acceptance.suite.yml file structure is

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - WebDriver:
                url: http://localhost:81/project
                browser: 'chrome'
                window_size: 1024x768
                wait: 10
        - \Helper\Acceptance
```

2)I have kept both selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar and chromedriver.exe in same folder.

I tried launching my selenium server with the command `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\stuff\sel\codeceptiontest\chromedriver.exe`

3)I am getting an error `"Error: Could not find or load main class ="`

4)Is this the right command to run my file ?
`php codecept.phar run tests/acceptance/loginCept.php --env chrome`

Comment: So your issue is that you can't start selenium, right?

Comment: Yes. I can't start selenium. I am getting the error which I have specified above. And are my settings in acceptance yml are right?

Comment: Are you able to open the jar using Winzip. It might be corrupt!

Answer (score 0):

You can run Chrome Web Driver and Selenium Server separately. They work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install chrome driver first and run like this

java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.52.0.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/Users/ravis/Downloads/chromedriver

2. in yml file:

class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - WebDriver:
            url: http://google.com
            browser: firefox
        - \Helper\Acceptance

env:
    chrome:
         modules:
            config:
                WebDriver:
                    browser: 'chrome'

it will override the firefox and will set environment for chrome. u can try it if you want.

3. run cmd: codecept run acceptance Loginfile --env chrome

hope it works for you.